# IONIC 3 ts image clickable

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

[Doubt IONIC 3 - ts]
I'm trying to make an image with clickable parts using SVG, using this type of code
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp
but when I give ionic serves on the pc (desktop mode) it works normal, if by in cellular mode it does not work anymore.
By placing the app on your phone it no longer works ...
Anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you
My code:

```html
<img src="assets/img/novapec.png" width="100%;" usemap="#image-map">
   
    <map name="image-map">
        <area (click) = "SVGTEST('P1.5')" target="" alt="P1.5" title="P1.5"  coords="107,430,30,524,126,515" shape="rect">
        <area (click) = "SVGTEST('P1.4')" target="" alt="P1.4" title="P1.4"  coords="888,468,877,446,860,415,841,371,828,344,805,319,759,283,728,324,863,473,840,473,815,475,788,478,718,437,714,412,724,403,738,397,749,384,765,371,768,368,835,440,860,472" shape="poly">
    </map>
```